# default login for ubuntu 18.04.2 on SmartOS

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, smartos

Does anyone know how to either login, run vmadm console with an ssh key or reset the password for a fresh Ubuntu KVM-VM installation on SmartOS?

I created the KVM-VM of Ubuntu 18.04.2 from a SmartOS image with uuid 9aa48095-da9d-41ca-a094-31d1fb476b98. The VM is in state of running and when entering vmadm console it runs into a login prompt.

I tried the combinations i found online:

```
root:
root:root
ubuntu:
ubuntu:ubuntu
```

but none of them worked.

i added `"customer_metadata": {"root_authorized_keys": "ssh-ed25519 AA...7 name"}`, to the VM-Config, but i still can't connect via vmadm console, since i don't know to point the my private key file.

I also tried connecting via VNC and via VNC with an auth-key, but there I still get the same login prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding an external IP and the following line to the "customer_metadata" in the create script, i could connect from smartos, but not from my laptop:
`"user-script" : "/usr/sbin/mdata-get root_authorized_keys > ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys ; /usr/sbin/mdata-get root_authorized_keys > ~admin/.ssh/authorized_keys"`